# Expresso Store, USPS shipping options for individual products?

Tags: expresso-store, expresso, extension, shipping

I'm using the USPS Shipping plugin to calculate shipping in my store. We use USPS Flat Rate Boxes to ship and most products fit in those boxes. In order to pull the correct shipping rates during checkout I have to set the container to "Flat Rate Box" in the shipping extension settings.

This works great, except we have couple products that do not fit in a flat rate box and need special packaging. When I try to add one of these products to the cart I get an error stating:

> Store (Shipping): The entered length must be less than or equal to 11.00000 inches.

Is it possible to use the USPS Shipping extension but set a custom shipping option for the individual products that need a custom option?

So far I have been unable to find a solution.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way currently to set the shipping type per product in Store.

You have two options really.

You could modify the current USPS plugin to allow for selection of both Flat Rate boxes and normal shipping boxes with some logic that would default to flat rate for items that would fit into flat rate boxes. Then larger items would calculate based upon the normal boxes for the correct shipping cost.

I have not tested this but you should also be able to duplicate the USPS gateway file with a slightly different name then rename all of the classes to match and then you would be able to setup both gateways separately for flat rate and normal boxes.